# How to build a simple custom widget with Qt?

Tags: qt

How to build a simple custom widget with Qt? The widget is very simple with just 2 line edit `QLineEdit' in a vertical box layout`QVBoxLayout`. How to do it? I read Qt's examples on custom widget generation. They reimplement paint event to rendering the custom widget. However, mine is so simple that I cannot find a solution in Qt's reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to do it all programatically it would look something like this:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
    public:
        MyWidget(QWidget *parent=0) : QWidget(parent) {
            QVboxLayout *layout = new QVboxLayout();
            setLayout(layout);
            layout->addWidget(new QLineEdit());
            layout->addWidget(new QLineEdit());
        }
};
```

Depending on your needs you could make the line edits member variables and manipulate them as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks. It is like building a dialog but subclassing `QWidget`.